# In place constrution of member variable via constructor

Tags: c++, construction, in-place

Take the following class:

```
template <typename TPayload>
class Message
{
    public:
        Message(const TPayload& payload)
             : m_header(sizeof(TPayload)),
               m_payload(payload) {}

    private:
        const Header   m_header;
        const TPayload m_payload;
};
```

Whenever I construct a Message I have to create a TPayload (the parameter payload), copy this into m_payload, and then destruct payload. Now consider this can be done 100'000s of times a second, I think this is a wasted effort.

My question is, can I force an inplace construction of m_payload to avoid the tempory payload?

One possible solution I am considering is overloading the construction many times like below but to be honest with all the copying of the multiple argumwents I'm doubting there is much saving.

```
template <typename TPayload>
class Message
{
    public:
        template <typename A>
        Message(const A& a)
             : m_header(sizeof(TPayload)),
               m_payload(a) {}

        template <typename A, typename B>
        Message(const A& a, const B& b)
             : m_header(sizeof(TPayload)),
               m_payload(a, b) {}

    private:
        const Header   m_header;
        const TPayload m_payload;
};
```

Comment: Is this a pseudocode?  You should try compiling code before posting, or atleast should mention that this is pseudocode and hence woudn't compile.

Comment: It's a simplification of the classes I am writing, more for demonstration purposes. Corrected a few missing brackets :)

Comment: Not only are the brackets missing, the code is even correct. If you post this, how would we infer seeing your code how much you already know? The indication that I get seeing your code, that you don't template, and have never written code using it.

Comment: If you construct your message using temporaries, e.g: `Message<Foo>(Foo(bar))`, the optimizer will eliminate redundant copies and should effectively construct the object "in place". I'm not 100% sure about this. If I'm wrong, I'm sure I'll get pummelled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is *forwarding* of constructor arguments given to `Message` to the constructor of `Message::m_payload`.

This can be done neatly in C++11 (using variadic templates and `std::forward`, as used in `std::vector<>::emplace_back()` and many other functions) or with several overloads in C++03, as you started writing, and as used `in boost::make_shared<>`

for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
typedef size_t Header;
template <typename TPayload>
class Message
{
    public:
        template <typename ...Args>
        Message(Args&&... args)
             : m_header(sizeof(TPayload)),
               m_payload(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
               {}
        void show_payload() const
        {
                std::cout << m_payload << '\n';
        }
    private:
        const Header   m_header;
        const TPayload m_payload;
};

int main()
{
     Message<std::string> test(10, 'a');
     test.show_payload();

     Message<double> test2(3.14);
     test2.show_payload();
}
```

test run: https://ideone.com/J1JnZ

Answer (score 2):

Also in C++11, you can accept the parameter by value, then move construct it:

```
Message(TPayload payload)
    :m_header(sizeof(TPayload)),
     m_payload(std::move(payload)) {}
```

Just make sure TPayload has a properly defined and useful move constructor, otherwise this won't do much good.

Comment: +1 This also works in C++ 03, only then you have to default construct the payload member and then `swap()` it with the argument. Of course this means that the payload has to have a default constructor. Or at least a very "cheap" constructor - i.e. one that doesn't do much (doesn't allocate memory or such).

Comment: @pgroke and the member has to be non-const.

Comment: @Mark B: Right. I didn't see that. Should be possible to arrange though.